# Least ordinal not embedded in a total order

Tags: reference-request, peano-arithmetic, ordinal-numbers, linear-orders, ordered-fields

If $(E,<)$ is a linear order, let $s(E,<)$ denote the least ordinal which doesn't embed in $(E,<)$.

I am trying to prove the following:

- If $(M,+,.,0,1)$ is a model of open induction, (or equivalently, the set of positive elements of an integer part of a real closed field) then $s(M,<)$ where $x < y$ is defined by $\exists z(z \neq 0 \wedge x + z = y)$ is regular.

I can prove this when no element of $M$ has a cofinal sequence of powers using a real closed field having $M \cup (-M)$ as an integer part. However, I wonder if my proof misses the point.

I am trying to find some literature about $s(E,<)$ where it could have been studied and where its regularity may have been questioned. Does anyone know where to find such study?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim isn't true.

For a counterexample, let's construct a $\kappa$-like model. A model of arithmetic (or indeed any ordered structure) is $\kappa$-like, if it has size $\kappa$, but every proper initial segment of it has size less than $\kappa$.

One can construct a $\kappa$-like model $M\models\text{PA}$ for any uncountable $\kappa$, including singular $\kappa$, by iteratively using the MacDowell-Specker theorem, which asserts that every model of arithmetic has a proper elementary end-extension (and so it has one of the same cardinality). Specifically, let $M_0\models\text{PA}$ be any countable model of arithmetic, and construct a tower of end-extensions 
$$M_0\prec_e M_1\prec_e\dots\prec_e M_\alpha\prec_e M_{\alpha+1}\prec_e\dots\prec_e M$$
where at successor stages we apply the MacDowell-Specker theorem, choosing $M_{\alpha+1}$ to have the same size as $M_\alpha$, and at limit stages take unions. Let $M=\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa}M_\alpha$ be the model at stage $\kappa$, which will be $\kappa$-like, since the initial segments are contained in the various $M_\alpha$, which have size $|\alpha\cdot\omega|$, which is less than $\kappa$.

It follows that $\kappa$ order-embeds into $\langle M,<\rangle$, since we added new points on top at each stage, but $\kappa+1$ does not embed, since no bounded segment of $M$ has size $\kappa$. So your characteristic $s(M,<)$ will be $\kappa+1$, which is not a regular cardinal. So this is a counterexample.

You asked for literature, and there seems to be a lot of work on $\kappa$-like models, such as:

- R. Kaye, Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic, [The theory of $\kappa$-like models of arithmetic](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.ndjfl/1040136915), vol. 36, no. 4, 1995.

Comment: This is very helpful. I realise that what I claimed I proved was wrong too because I proved it for $s(E,<)$ being defined as the supremum of the ordinals which embed in $(E,<)$, which is different.

Comment: Yes, those are different, since in the case of my $\kappa$-like model, the supremum will be $\kappa$. But the construction shows that this, too, can be singular.

Comment: Yes, and your counter example made me find the error in my proof. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a precision: I understand that at limit $\alpha$, $M_{\alpha}$ is a model of open induction because open induction has $\forall \exists$-axiomatisations, but why would it be a model of full PA?

Comment: The union of a chain of elementary extensions is an elementary extension, and so all the models have the same theory.

Comment: Yes, sorry I thought they were just extensions.